# Ionic emulate android ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED localhost:8100

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I try to emulate my Ionic application on Android. Once my application start in the emulated device, it breaks with the following error:

> **Application Error**
>
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://localhost:8100)

and also

```
Webpage not available

The webpage at http://localhost:8100 could not be loaded because: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Debugging same project works like a charm in browser and in iOS debugger.

cordova-plugin-whitelist is already installed and I have the following rule in my config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost*"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it will be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/48014576/20965504

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution, I was running the command

```
ionic run android -c -s -l --address localhost
```

Removing `--address localhost` from the command solve my problem means following command is ok

```
ionic run android -c -s -l
```

Quite funny, since adding that parameter, let me run my App in the iOS debugger respectively in case of iOS was a must.

Comment: `-c` equal to `--consolelogs`, `-s`equal to `--serverlogs`, `-l` equal to `--livereload`

Comment: The command for Ionic 3 changed to ionic cordova run android -c -s -l

Answer (score 8):

You might want to try running

```
adb reverse tcp:8100 tcp:8100
```

Especially in case its a new device / emulator, so that port forwarding gets set up.

Comment: thanks man, it worked.

Comment: @NikBarres - what does this command do?

Answer (score 2):

Using the following command solve the issue for me on ionic 5 with capacitor

```
ionic capacitor run android -l --address 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've got was to use my machine IP address instead of localhost for the API call

e.g.

NOK API endpoint: 'http://localhost:3002/api/'

OK API endpoint: 'http://192.168.1.XXX:3002/api/'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am confused but `ionic emulate` would try to launch in an emulator.

`ionic serve` would fire up the webserver

Comment: I run the command "ionic emulate android -c -s -l --address localhost" which give me that error back. "ionic serve browser -l -c -s" and "ionic run ios -c -s -l --address localhost" are working fine respectively don't have that or any problem with my app.

Answer (score 0):

ionic serve is used for web based app which opens in the default browser

and `ionic run android -l -c` opens it on your device which is connected your pc and port forwarded using chrome inspect.

Both above automatically assign host/IP with port number

you can see in your cmd/gitbash

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue when running `ionic run android -c -l -s` and calling api in `emulator`

Solutions

1. Restarting the device fixed the issue.
2. Please check your proxy api is same as Running dev server