# Ionic 2 - Error : net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when run on android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, httprequest

(Sorry for my bad English)

I have built an application with Ionic 2 for Android. In this application I need to get information from an API and it's works perfectly when I run do it in the browser (ionic serve).

The problem is when I run on my device (Android 6.0.1) I get this issue :

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Then I searched how to resolve this and I tried many things.

I have the cordova-plugin-whitelist and my config.xml looks like :

```
<content src="index.html" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
```

and I put this in my index.html :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; media-src *;">
```

I have read many documentation concerning this issue but I didn't find anything really helpful.

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: what is the api you are using ?

Comment: I use an API from my own website, it's a classic get request for check the existance of an user : /rest/login then with a basic authorization

Comment: you are pi is hosted or on localhost ?

Comment: Not on localhost, hosted

Comment: @Chabrioche i guess your ajax request is getting timed out. Ensure that the  resource you are trying to access via the app is directly accessible in mobile browser first

Comment: @Gandhi, you really live up to your name ! Ty for your help, I had a revelation with your comment. Then I solved the problem. It was I tried to access to api in 4G but the api is on localhost... sorry Oussema...

Comment: @Chabrioche Thanks for the comment. I m humbled. Posted the answer for the benefit of others. Accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An obvious connectivity issue as stated in the error.

Ensure that the resource you are trying to access via the app is directly accessible in mobile browser first. If you ensure its accessibility in device browser, then the app connectivity issue will be resolved for sure. Cheers

Comment: "Ensure that the resource you are trying to access via the app is directly accessible in mobile browser first."
How can I ensure that ?

Comment: @TzviGregoryKaidanov for instance, if you are trying to access an URL, ensure that u are able to access the URL in mobile browser first

Answer (score 11):

All I have to do is to make sure `ionic cordova run android -l -c -s` works on my android phone.

1. Both my laptop and phone is on the same network.
2. I can access to the livereload server (on my laptop). E.g.
   http://192.168.1.5:8100 can be access on my phone chrome browser.

If step 2 cannot be done. Do the following on Windows 10 to enable the firewall setting on my laptop for Node.js
[Click here for picture of Enable firewall configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWUeC.png)

Comment: Avast Internet Security was treating my local network as public and preventing the connection

Comment: Worked for me and Ionic DevApp is running.

Answer (score 2):

**Ionic 4** Solution(*100% working*):

- run command - `ionic serve --devapp`
- Go to - "Windows defender Security Center" in Windows 10. Disable your domain, private & public networks in the firewall.
- Also, "Clear all app data" in your devApp (option in side nav bar).

Enjoy live-reloading of your new app in the real device!

Answer (score 1):

On windows, it's a firewall issue. Disabling firewall works but it's not recommended. Just add Node.js in firewall exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu this issue may be sometimes related to the firewall. I had this issue and tried everything but nothing worked.
At last i disabled my ubuntu's firewall and it worked like a charm.
In ubuntu, UFW is the default firewall.
You can disable it by:   **sudo ufw disable**
Check its status:  **sudo ufw status**
Enable it later on: **sudo ufw enable**

(Be sure to keep the device and the system in the same network)
Hope this helps, as it helped me.

Comment: U r god! I was facing this issue since last 2 days with node as a server. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your `confix.xml` file

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```